# easyphp mysql port error- could not connect to mysql port(3306) as it is being used by another process

Tags: php, easyphp

I installed `easyphp` but I already have MySQL installed on my computer on port 3306 and `easyphp` also requires the same port hence this is giving an error. Can anything can be done besides uninstalling MySQL??

Comment: easyphp includes mysql, so you're trying to run it twice. So yeah, either uninstall your original mysql, or use something other than easyphp.

Answer (score 1):

I opened my local Windows Services, found the MySQL service running (in my case, MySQL56) and stopped it. Then I went back to EasyPHP and started MySQL and it started without complaining this time